# Not using the common preposition of a verb

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Consider:

> Table 1 shows the number of rules required to extract the main article **for** each website.

vs.

> Table 1 shows the number of rules required to extract the main article **from** each website.

**From** is the common preposition for "extract", while **for** is also meaningful as we can say it shows X for each Y. Then sometimes I don't know which is better to be used!

Other examples:

> Moreover, removing distracting parts **from/on** a web page can enhance the page readability
>
> For a simpler task such as extracting the main articles **from/on/in/of** a news website, the features they provide can be excessive.

Comment: I am working on prepositions, However, I've concluded that the best rule is using the correct collocation. I use Oxford dictionary which clearly determines what preposition should be used. If I want to write a sentence, I use the pattern " extract sth from sth " as it declared in Oxford.

Comment: @Cardinal yes "from" is for extract but "for" is also for "show", here they give different structures to the sentence, that's my main confusion

Comment: In that case you might want to add a comma after '*article*'.

Comment: I am confused. As I see, you want to extract sth from each website ? don you ? or you want to show sth for each website ? What is your intent ? or what is the intents behind the table. 1

Comment: @Cardinal the template is Table 1 shows the number of rules (...) for each website

Comment: @VictorBazarov yes but which is more common, how can I know which is more suitable in any case

Comment: I think above two sentences convey different information thus, I think it highly depends on the author's intent.

Answer (score 1):

From is the correct preposition for extract.

However, the first sentence can still be considered correct if "for" is associated with "required. In that case, the sentence is correct but could be improved with the order:

> Table 1 shows the number of rules required for each website to extract the main article. (This has a different meaning, which could be wrong in your context)

The verb "extract" has to have an object, but a prepositional phrase is not strictly required. All the examples you provide have a preposition that can function as a modifier of something else in the sentence.